# Why doesn't my In App Purchase purchase the product?

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

I'm calling this function when I press a button to unlock a level but nothing happens when I do this. It runs the function but it doesn't ask for my password or anything else. What am I doing wrong?

```
func callthis() {

    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        println("IAP is enabled, loading")
        var productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: "unlockLevelTwoPlease")
        var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        println("please enable IAPS")

    }
}



func callthis2() {

    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        println("IAP is enabled, loading")
        var productID:NSSet = NSSet(object:  "unlockLevelThreePlease")
        var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        println("please enable IAPS")

    }
}



func callthis3() {

    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        println("IAP is enabled, loading")
        var productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: "unlockLevelFourPlease")
        var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        println("please enable IAPS")

    }
}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {



    var touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch
    var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)


    if node.name == "unlockleveltwobutton" {
        callThis()

        for product in list {
            var prodID = product.productIdentifier
            if(prodID == "unlockLevelTwoPlease") {
                p = product
                buyProduct()
                break;


            }
        }
        runAction(menuAudioPlayer)



    }


    if node.name == "unlocklevelthreebutton" {

        callThis2()

        for product in list {
            var prodID = product.productIdentifier
            if(prodID == "unlockLevelThreePlease") {
                p = product
                buyProduct()
                break;
            }

        }
        runAction(menuAudioPlayer)





    }


    if node.name == "unlocklevelfourbutton" {


        callthis3()


        for product in list {
            var prodID = product.productIdentifier
            if(prodID == "unlockLevelFourPlease") {
                p = product
                buyProduct()
                break;

            }
        }
        runAction(menuAudioPlayer)


    }
```

Comment: I don't get what your saying?

Comment: 1: Apple purchases not always work from Simulator, I hope it's fixed now. For iOS7 it's definatelly not working, only on device.

you have a lot of console logs... in which state are you stuck?

Comment: I got it to work but its not unlocking the levels until I close and open my app. Once the purchase is completed I want it to unlock.   Can you take a look at my code:  @Jaro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122498/will-my-app-get-rejected-if-the-user-has-to-close-and-open-the-app-to-unlock-the

Comment: I'm not so good in Swift yet but don't you have to call "synchronize" method on NSUserDefaults as an immediate save? otherwise is does the actual saving who knows when. Upvote if yes :)

Comment: What part of the code are you looking at?

Comment: Post buyProduct(). Post how you're handling the notifications from the transaction observer. Post what you're doing after you finish the transaction. The things that happen when you initiate a purchase are asynchronous and you need to handle them when they come back. As an aside, _based on this code_, it appears you don't yet understand the _fundamentals_ of the in-app purchase flow, which will lead you into any number of dead-ends as far as your code is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

From your code it looks like you haven't identified the asynchronous mode of in-app purchases. The whole process is done in steps, with various actors performing each step, and it cannot be described by the linear calls you have listed above.

In-app purchase is **broadly made up** of 3 distinct steps:

1 - **Getting products from itunes store** and displaying them on UI (Store UI which displays product titles, description, price in user-understandable way)

2 - **Providing mechanism for user to purchase products** from UI (IBActions that enable "Buy" action)

3 - **Handling post-purchase** (handle successful purchase by unlocking the product, handle failed purchase by displaying user-understandable error, and handle future restore for non-consumable products as they must not be purchased again as per the rules set by Apple)

This is what you must do. If you are looking for step by step tutorial on how to integrate IAP - here is my [own tutorial](http://www.iphonegamezone.net/make-money-appstore-ios-in-app-purchase-tutorial/) to simplify what I wrote above.

If you need more efficient solution, here is [video lecture series](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-ios-moneymaking-course-learn-in-app-purchases/?couponCode=PROMO29SO) with SWIFT and Objective C. It also accompanies code samples for both.

Comment: I didn't post the whole code. This is just some of the code that I thought would be enough to find the problem.The problem im having now is that when I press on the button to buy a level I have to tap it twice to start the payment process or else it won't work. Do you know why that happens? @NiravBhatt

Comment: Your touchesbegan is buggy because buyProduct() - which supposedly buys the product needs paymentqueue addpayment call. This call can happen only on a valid SKProduct object. A valid SKProduct object can only be constructed from didReceiveResponse delegate method of SKProductsRequestDelegate, which is missing here, and you are calling everything [request.start() + buyProduct] synchronously which obviously points out that you don't have a valid SKProduct object at all.

Comment: I have the productRequest Deleagate....would you like to see the entire code. I would really appreciate if you could take a look at it and see what Im doing wrong.@NiravBhatt

Comment: you there @NiravBhatt