# Will my app get rejected if the user has to close and open the app to unlock the in app purchase?

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

Sorry for all the code I just want to get this right. I have three different in app purchases and this is my code in the GameViewController. I called the functions in my viewDidLoad() function. Does anyone see anything wrong with the code?

EDIT:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  callthis()
  callthis2()
  callthis3()
}    

func callthis() {
  if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
    println("IAP is enabled, loading")
    var productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: "unlockLevelTwo")
    var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
  } else {
    println("please enable IAPS")
  }
}

func callthis2() {
  if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
    println("IAP is enabled, loading")
    var productID:NSSet = NSSet(object:  "unlockLevelThree")
    var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
  } else {
    println("please enable IAPS")
  }
}

func callthis3() {
  if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
    println("IAP is enabled, loading")
    var productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: "unlockEverything")
    var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
  } else {
    println("please enable IAPS")
  }
}

func RestorePurchases() {
  SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
  SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
  println("Can't make purchases")
}

var list = [SKProduct]()
var p = SKProduct()

func buyProduct() {
  println("buy" + p.productIdentifier)
  var pay = SKPayment(product: p)
  SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
  SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
}

func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
  var myProduct = response.products

  for product in myProduct {
    println("product added")
    println(product.productIdentifier)
    println(product.localizedTitle)
    println(product.localizedDescription)
    println(product.price)

    list.append(product as! SKProduct)
  }  
}

func request(request: SKRequest!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
  println("Error fetching product info")
}

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
  println("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");
  for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
    var trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
    println(trans.error)
    switch trans.transactionState {
    case .Purchased, .Restored:
      let prodID = trans.payment.productIdentifier as String
      switch prodID {
      case "unlockLevelTwo":
        println("unlocksleveltwo")
        NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "Leavel2")
        gameScene.unlockLevelTwoPlease()
      case "unlockLevelThree":
        println("unlocklevelthree")
        NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "Leavel3")
        gameScene.unlockLevelThreePlease()
      case "unlockEverything":
        println("unlockeverything")
        NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "Leavel2")
        gameScene.unlockLevelTwoPlease()
        NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "Leavel3")
        gameScene.unlockLevelThreePlease()
        defaults.setBool(true , forKey: "removeAdsPurchased")
      default:
        println("unlocksEverything")
      }
      queue.finishTransaction(trans)
      break;
    case .Failed:
      println("Purchased Failed");
      queue.finishTransaction(trans)
      break;
    default:
      println("default")
      break;
    }
  }
}

func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction) {
  println("finish trans")
  SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(trans)
}

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, removedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
  println("remove trans");
}
```

Then in my GameScene.swift file I do this:

```
if node.name == "unlockleveltwobutton" {
  for product in viewController.list {
    var prodID = product.productIdentifier
    if(prodID == "unlockLevelTwo") {
      viewController.p = product
      viewController.buyProduct()
      break;
    }
  }
  runAction(menuAudioPlayer)
}
if node.name == "unlocklevelthreebutton" {
  for product in viewController.list {
    var prodID = product.productIdentifier
    if(prodID == "unlockLevelThree") {
      viewController.p = product
      viewController.buyProduct()
      break;
    }
  }
  runAction(menuAudioPlayer)
}
if node.name == "specialdeal" {
  for product in viewController.list {
    var prodID = product.productIdentifier
    if(prodID == "unlockEverything") {
      viewController.p = product
      viewController.buyProduct()
      break;
    }
  }
  runAction(menuAudioPlayer)
}
```

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We have nothing to do with Apple or its app approval process.

Comment: okay ill change the question so its a programming question.

Comment: Yes, Apple will likely reject an app that doesn't appear to respond to a successful purchase. You'll need to catch the purchase response, then update the user's data accordingly. If you post some code, and add details as to why you're having trouble doing that, I'm sure we can help you figure it out.

Comment: okay give me a sec ill post the code!

Comment: @Orkster I added the code in the op, can you take a look at it?

Comment: I see that you're saving the purchased levels to NSUserDefaults, then calling a method to unlock the level in the game. Inside unlockLevelTwoPlease(), I would assume you have code that makes the level visible/playable. So nothing jumps out as being wrong. What is the behavior you're seeing vs. what you want to see?

Comment: Everything works fine it's just that it doesn't unlock the level when it gets purchased. I have to close and open my app to get that to work.

Comment: @Orkster I want it to unlock the level when the purchase is complete. I don't want to have to close my app and open it just to unlock the level. I think that not a good user experience and will probably get my app rejected.

Comment: I think we need to see what logic you have in 'unlockLevelTwoPlease()' then. Also, are you sure the unlock method is actually being called when you run the app?

Comment: Ill update the code @Orkster.

Comment: The logic in unlockLevelTwoPlease is a image of level two so when its unlocked you get to tap it and go into level two.

Comment: @coding22, Just my two cents here. I am not sure how your project is setup. But maybe during first launch, set some default "NSUserDefaults" like lvl1 and set to true, lvl2 set to false etc.  Then when the purchase is completed, update the related NSUserDefault to true. Then when you call what ever function(like a menu btn) you use to load lvl2/lvl3/lvl4. Just check that the related NSUserDefault is "true" if so load. If not pop alert with link to purchase lvl2/lvl3/lvl4 etc. This way you dont need to reload the app to unlock the purchased lvl.

Comment: I got it to work but I have to press on the button twice to initiate the payment for some reason. If I press the button once nothing happens. @the_pantless_coder